# Put files outside of directory, so none can access it (Apache, PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I have a file structure like this:

```
public/admin
public/some folder
includes/
```

I set up a sub-domain `page.mysite.com` and I pointed the directory to be `mysite.com/page/public/admin`. I thought that it would work ok, but it seems that it's not loading contents that are outside of admin (in this case target folder), so it can't see any files outsite admin.

What could the problem be?

P.S. I have a shared hosting, so I can access only Cpanel and FTP (just in case you know).

Answer (score 1):

If your shared hosting is on a LAMP stack it is probably using a virtual host in Apache to handle the requests for the sub domain.

The Apache configuration will define /page/public/admin as the DocumentRoot of the sub domain page.mysite.com.

The Apache user can only access files to which it has permissions - in a shared setup like yours, this is likely to only be in child directories of the root directory, not in parent directories.

So, this is not a problem, it is a plan of your provider - it protects all files at a higher level than your public web root.

If you had a shell on the server you could use chown to give the appropriate permissions.  However, with the limited access you have, I'd imagine your only route forward is to move all the files you need into a sub directory of /page/public/admin.